# How to read h5 file to save many data-frames into Excel file

Tags: python, dataframe, h5py

I have h5 file contains node paths like "Events/Gait/Lower Limb/Initial Contact Next". The number of rows of each node path is not the same (25 rows, 113 rows, 21 rows, 1 row, 22 rows or 15744 rows), as the number of columns are not the same as well. I am looking to combine the values of all path nodes, which has the same number of rows into data frames with removing the parentheses and then save it to many sheets in Excel file. Also, I am looking to split each item in each dataframe, which have more than one component, in many columns before save it to Excel file. Please not, the number of components of each item is not the same.

This example explains what I am looking to do, This data set contain (4 columns and 3 row):

1- Dataframe 2 - sheet 2 - Excel file 1:

name/one            name/two           name/three                name1432/fou

(192.26949,)          (34.56,)    (435.54,436.65,87.3,5432)            (1.2,)

(189.4033245,)        (58.654,)   (45.51,56.612, 54253.543, 54.321)    (1.54,)

(184.4593252,)        (6543.6543,) (45.58,56.6412,654.876,765.66543)   (1543.5,)

The  Dataframe 1 - sheet 1 - Excel file 1 should be like before saving to Excel file. The dataframe above should be converted to 7 columns and 3 rows.

name/one                     name/two                       name/three1

192.26949                     34.56                          435.54

189.4033245                   58.654                          45.51

184.4593252                   6543.6543                         45.58

name/three2        name/three3        name/three4     name1432/fou
 436.65               87.3               5432            1.2

56.612            54253.543            54.321           1.54

56.6412           654.876             765.66543        1543.5

The code below explains what I did, I just have a problem to remove all parentheses and commas and split each item, which contains more than one item, into two or more than two columns before saving the datframes to Excel file:

```
dfd = {}  
#{1:df1,5:df2,113:df3<-add col} 

def print_attrs(name, obj):
    global dfd
    if '<class \'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset\'>' == str(type(obj)):
        k= str(len(obj))
        if k not in dfd.keys():
            df = pd.DataFrame()
            #print(name,"Adding new key for len ", k)
        else:
            df = dfd[k]
        df[name] = obj
        df[name] = re.findall(r"\'([A-Za-z]+)\'", df[name])

        df[name] = " ".join(df[name])

        dfd[k] = df      
        l = len(obj[0])

f = h5py.File('walking5.h5', 'r')
f.visititems(print_attrs)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hd5excelout120.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for k, df in dfd.items():
    print(k,len(df))
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet_len_'+k)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I need to your help to solve this problem.

Comment: It's hard to see what you are doing. Please clean-up formatting of your code, including indentation.

Comment: I have received problem to save the changes when I tried to  clean up formatting of my code

Comment: you can see my code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oj_7JxMderaoUz6O0rDUAb2deg299dbH/view?usp=sharing